# Map string array to object keys and get values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array of string used in select element (multi select) options.

`let array = ["one", "two", "three"];`

Also I have following Object.

`{ "one" : ['apple','orange','banana'], "two" : ['cucumber','onion'], "three" : ['potato','radish','carot']};`

I select one & two and I want to combine
`['apple','orange','banana']` and `['cucumber','onion']` in another select dropdown.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: ```['apple','orange','banana','cucumber','onion']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the array and get the corresponding array in the object and [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the result:

```js
let array = ["one", "two"];
let obj = {
  "one": ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'],
  "two": ['cucumber', 'onion'],
  "three": ['potato', 'radish', 'carot']
};
const result = array.map(e => obj[e]).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in conjunction with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
let chosen = ['one', 'two'];
let obj = { "one" : ['apple','orange','banana'], "two" : ['cucumber','onion'], "three" : ['potato','radish','carot']};
const res = chosen.reduce((acc, curr)=>acc.concat(obj[curr]), []);
console.log(res);
```